# Mongodb: read documents/arrays and delete them immediately

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

**Technical Background:** I'm using tokumx (support [document level locking](http://docs.tokutek.com/tokumx/tokumx-concurrency.html#tokumx-concurrency-document-level-locks)) and php.

The document structure is like this

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "username": "1",
    },
    {
      "username": "2",
    }
  ],
  "site": "test.com"
}
```

**Situation:**

Most of the time, I only need **first x accounts** from "accounts" array.

The minutes **these first x accounts** are retrieved, they should be deleted from the "accounts" array in the document.

**Compromise I can make:**

extract out "accounts".

```
  {
    "username" : "1",
    "site": "test.com"
  },

  {
    "username" : "2",
    "site": "test.com"
  }
```

Or switch to MySql (last option).

---

Comment: @Trudbert MongoDB has a way to do this. Don't know about the tokmux part, but it is natively handled.

Comment: Jup therefore comment removed and answer in drafting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was almost a comment, but it's a long comment with more explaination and example given. Personally not that familiar with tokumx ( as in, I just have never used it ), but MongoDB itself has a way to do this, and it's the [.`findAndModify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findandmodify.php) method.

Basically you are "updating" the document or "removing" in this case, but you have the option to see either the "pre-modified" or "post-modified" form in the returned result.

So to work with an array then you call like this:

```
 $doc = $collection->findAndModify(
     array(),                                       # Something representing the "query"
     array( 
         '$pull' => array(                          # Basicallly the update
             'accounts' => array( 'username' => 1 ) 
         )
     ),
     null,                                          # optional projected fields
     array(                                         # this is the "options"
         "new" => FALSE,                            # which is the default
     )
 );
```

And for a plain document:

```
 $doc = $collection->findAndModify(
     array( 'username' => 1 ),             
     array(),                                       # update, doesn't matter
     null,
     array( "remove" => TRUE )
 );
```

Noting your comment, you remove the first `n` elements of an array using the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator funnily enough. There is a [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier that does this:

```
 $doc = $collection->findAndModify(
     array(),                                       # Something representing the "query"
     array( 
         '$push' => array(                          # Basicallly the update
             'accounts' => array(
                 '$each' => array(),                # But blank
                 '$slice' => lengthOfArrayMinusNElements                
             )
         )
     ),
     null,                                          # optional projected fields
     array(                                         # this is the "options"
         "new" => FALSE,                            # which is the default
     )
 );
```

Not "super" atomic since you need to know "how long" the array is, but it can be done. It seems odd I know, but you are basically adding "nothing" to the array but limiting it's length and removing elements via `$slice`. Two forms, one is for projection, the other is an update modifier as shown.

Comment: thanks for posting php example. Hope you don't mind another question, could you show me how to use $slice x array "accounts" in findAndModify if it's possible.

Comment: I guess, it's third arguments. `array( 'accounts' => array('$slice' => 5))` thank you again!

Comment: @Jesse I saw you comment on the other answer already. There is a way to do what you asked. Not ideal, but you can do it.

Comment: @Jesse and to clarify, the "third" or "fields" option is only a "projection" of the fields returned in the "found" document. It does not "modify" unless you do as I did in the last example.

Comment: honestly, the approach of removing first x elements looks weird to newbie like me. It's very bad habit but I have one more question, if I choose the plain document strucutre, how do I make the "query" to return first 50 documents of site test.com:  `array( 'site' => 'test.com', '$limit' => 50 )` ?

Comment: There are modifiers to methods like `.find()` that do that. The `.find()` method returns a "cursor" object, so various modifiers can be applied before the query is executed. This is well documented, but if you truly have more problems understanding then you can always ask another question. It's the best way to do so, and it keeps it clear and clean in the Q&A format of StackOverflow. That is the intent. One question, one answer.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'll figure out how to limit the number of affected results in findAndModify on my own.  I'll accept your answer once I get time to test after dinner.

Comment: @Jesse `.findAndModify()` only alters **one** document. To change more that one you need to issue `.update()` with the "multi" option. But this does not return the content of the document, which is what you require. One of the "options" that can be passed is a "sort" specification. The purpose is to work out "which one document" to actually apply. There is no way to modify and return either the original or altered state of multiple documents in a single operation. And that is not what you asked originally.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure from the structure what you want to achieve but the operation you want for the first part is [findAndModify()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/). So stab in the dark (mogoshell since I dont't know the php driver)

```
db.accounts.findAndModify({query: {"site": "test.com", "accounts.username":"2"},
                           update : {$pull: {"accounts" :{ "username" : "2"}})
```

To retrieve only the first x elments of the array you can use the [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator in the projection part of your query so for example

```
db.accounts.find({},{ accounts : { $slice: 5 }})
```

or in the findAndModify add an

```
fields: { accounts : { $slice: 5 }}
```

Comment: thanks. I'll give it a try. No way to retrieve the first n elements from array "accounts", right?

Comment: added that to the answer

Comment: Can $slice be used together with findAndModify? sorry, it's my first time of using mongodb.

Comment: Yes it can. Added that too

Comment: @Trudbert actually the correct form of $slice here would be the $push argument modifier.

Comment: @NeilLunn my understanding was that he wants to retrieve the first elements of the array not remove them

Comment: @Trudbert All fine. We have a different interpretation. Still I did point that out and clarified that in both answer and comments already.

Comment: @Trudbert sorry for not making it clear and cause a misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem I learned something new too (like every time when I answered simultaneously with @NeilLunn) so everyone is happy I think